# Printing via Google Cloud Print

Tags: android, google-cloud-print

I am trying to print a .txt file that my application saves via FileWriter.

The file it saves is /sdcard/StudentLatePass.txt

When the print button is clicked, the SD file is saved and then it needs to print. I've been following the [google cloud print tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android).

```
package com.android.upgrayeddapps.latepass;



import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class StudentActivity extends Activity 
{
    EditText txtData;
    Button btnPrintTardy;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.student);

        //Displays the Custom dialog for student login
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        AlertDialog alertDialog;

        Context mContext = this;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) ;
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.studentlogin, null);

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        builder.setView(layout);            

        alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        txtData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        btnPrintTardy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrintTardy);
        btnPrintTardy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // write on SD card file data in the text box
            try {
                File myFile = new File("/sdcard/StudentLatePass.txt");
                myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = 
                                        new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                myOutWriter.append(txtData.getText());
                myOutWriter.close();
                fOut.close();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Done writing SD 'StudentLatePass.txt'",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }// onClick
        }); // btnWriteSDFile


        btnPrintTardy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Print using Google Cloud Print
            Intent printIntent = new Intent(this, PrintDialogActivity.class);
                printIntent.setDataAndType(docUri, "text/plain");
                printIntent.putExtra("title", "Student Late Pass");
                startActivity(printIntent);

            }// onClick
    });// btnPrintSDFile




    }

    // Clear all activities on the top of the stack and deliver the intent to (on top now) MainActivity with a new Intent
    public void onGotoLatePassActiviy(View View)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(View.getContext(), LatePassActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        StudentActivity.this.finish();
    }
}
```

For the life of me I have tried to change the docUri, docMimeType and docTitle to everything under the sun to print this file.

My current modified code is

```
btnPrintTardy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Print using Google Cloud Print
            Intent printIntent = new Intent(this, PrintDialogActivity.class);
                printIntent.setDataAndType(docUri, "text/plain");
                printIntent.putExtra("title", "Student Late Pass");
                startActivity(printIntent);

            }// onClick
    });// btnPrintSDFile
```

I am still getting red squigglies under the docUri, and when i pass the intent to [Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajuGC.jpg)

Comment: Hover over the "red squigglies" and what does it say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this and see what happens:

`Intent printIntent = new Intent(StudentActivity.this, PrintDialogActivity.class);`

That should resolve the first "red squigglies".

---

Here is what you could try for the URI problem.

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/StudentLatePass.txt");
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/*");
```

Comment: vwola, now do you know what i need to change the docUri to? The file it saves is at /sdcard/StudentLatePass.txt

Comment: I added some more information, let me know if it works. Give me a +1 if it works. =)

Comment: I think both of you just made my day.

Comment: Don't forget to +1 us if this was helpful to you. =)