# Barcode print on Android

Tags: android, printing, barcode

I want to send a barcode printout to a network printer through my Android handheld device. Both the devices are on the same wireless network. I can ping the printer on my laptop. 
Has anyone tried to print on Android?

Comment: Is google cloud print acceptable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9911848/eclipse-printing-via-google-cloud-print

Comment: thanks, ı know google cloud print but ı do not have internet. I have homegroup network. can you help me at that topic?